# Diferencia entre "push" y "push to upstream" en plugin (nativo) GitHub Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, github

trabajo con netbeans y la herramienta github que viene con las nuevas versiones de este IDE trae esas 2 opciones y aun no logro saber sus diferencias.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que recuerdo (hace tiempo no utilizo netbeans):

- `Push to Upstream` realiza un push al repo remoto como se esperarías digamos
- `Push` te abría un diálogo donde te permitía elegir cosas especificas del push, refs specs, tags, etc

Answer (score 0):

En realidad esto es una pregunta especifica de Netbeans, de hecho otras IDE cuentan con estas opciones.

Push: se abre un cuadro de diálogo para  especificar cuales [refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) debes realizar push , incluyendo tags, casos especiales como HEAD : refs / heads / master , etc

Push to Upstream: Realiza push al branch como un 
branch de seguimiento remoto.